# Tensorflow 2.0 Tensor Manipulation

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

wanted to reshape and combine two tensor in the tensorflow :

```
a = [[1, 3, 5],
     [7, 9, 11]]
```

a.shape = (2, 3)

```
b = [[2, 2, 6],
     [8, 10, 12]]
```

b.shape = (2, 3)

c = combine(a, b)

result of c should be :

```
c = [[[[1, 2], [3, 2], [5, 6]],
[[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]]]
```

c.shape = (1, 2, 3, 2)

I need to convert a and b into c?

PS : Needed some tensor manipulation function in use like tf.concat, tf.reshape, looping is too slow to handle huge data. Numpy is also an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `tf.stack` and `tf.expand_dims`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1, 3, 5],
                [7, 9, 11]])

b = tf.constant([[2, 2, 6],
                  [8, 10, 12]])

c = tf.expand_dims(tf.stack([a, b], axis=-1), axis=0)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[[ 1  2]
   [ 3  2]
   [ 5  6]]

  [[ 7  8]
   [ 9 10]
   [11 12]]]], shape=(1, 2, 3, 2), dtype=int32)
```

Or `tf.stack` and `tf.newaxis`

```
c = tf.stack([a, b], axis=-1)[tf.newaxis,...]
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[[ 1  2]
   [ 3  2]
   [ 5  6]]

  [[ 7  8]
   [ 9 10]
   [11 12]]]], shape=(1, 2, 3, 2), dtype=int32)
```